# Zend Navigation Menu Accordion

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I currently have a Navigation menu in my Zend project. What I want to do now, is to add an accordion to it, kind of like this http://jsfiddle.net/Yb23C/2/. But I seem to be unable to add it to the current Zend Navigation setup.

My Bootstrap.php has this in it:

```
$userconfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'menuLoggedUser');    
$usercontainer = new Zend_Navigation($userconfig);
Zend_Registry::set('user',$usercontainer);
```

In the layout.phtml I have this:

```
$menu = $this->navigation()->menu(Zend_Registry::get('user'));

$menuNoUl = explode("\n",$menu);
array_pop($menuNoUl);
array_shift($menuNoUl);

echo join(" ",$menuNoUl);
```

which appears inside `<ul>` tags.

I modified my navigation.xml to add the `<pages>` tag within the fileset groups to start testing:

```
   <menuLoggedUser>
         <home>
            <label>Home</label>
            <uri>/test/index</uri>
         </home>
         <filesets>
            <label>Filesets</label>
            <uri>javascript:void(0)</uri>
            <pages>
                <owner>
                    <label>Owner</label>
                    <uri>/test/filesets/owner</uri>
                </owner>
                <info>          
                    <label>Info</label>
                    <uri>/test/filesets/info</uri>
                </info>
                <quota>
                    <label>Quota</label>
                    <uri>/test/filesets/quota</uri>
                </quota>
            </pages>
         </filesets>
         <group>
        <label>Group</label>
        <uri>/test/groups/group</uri>
         </group>
          <user>
        <label>User Info</label>
        <uri>/test/user/usermanagement</uri>
         </user>
         <logout>
            <label>Logout</label>
            <uri>/test/index/logout</uri>
         </logout>
   </menuLoggedUser>
```

Which currently gives me this:

[image: Current menu without accordion]

I want those bullets to appear inside the accordion, so when a user clicks 'Filesets', the menu expands to show those bullets and when clicked again, hides them.

I've tried adding `->setMaxDepth(0)` and `->setMinDepth(1)` after `$menu = $this->navigation()->menu(Zend_Registry::get('user'))` but it does not give the results I want. I couldn't find any information on how to get it done using the Zend Navigation and I know for sure I can't be the first either. Thanks to whoever can help!

**EDIT**

Generated HTML code for Navigation, Before:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION_BEGIN -->
<div id="proj-navigation">
 <h2 class="proj-access">Start of left navigation</h2>
<ul id="proj-primary-links">
<li id="proj-overview"><a href="">W3</a></li>
    <li>         <a href="/index">Home</a>     </li>     
    <li>         <a href="/filesets/fileset">Filesets</a>     </li>     
    <li>         <a href="/index/logout">Logout</a>     </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- NAVIGATION_END -->
```

Generated HTML code for Navigation, With current changes:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION_BEGIN -->
<div id="proj-navigation">
 <h2 class="proj-access">Start of left navigation</h2>
<ul id="proj-primary-links">
<li id="proj-overview"><a href="">W3</a></li>
    <li>    <a href="/index.php/index">Home</a>     </li>     
    <li>    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Filesets</a>         
        <ul>

            <li>    <a href="/index.php/filesets/owner">Owner</a>   </li>             
            <li>    <a href="/index.php/filesets/info">Info</a> </li>             
            <li>    <a href="/index.php/filesets/quota">Quota</a>   </li>             

        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li>    <a href="/index/logout">Logout</a>     </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- NAVIGATION_END -->
```

**EDIT 2**

If I could just get the nested `<ul>`'s to have a class or ID, I'm sure I'd then be able to get my Accordion Navigation working, but whatever I try, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi, Could you provide generated html code for your menu ? Looks like you just need a bit of javascript to hide/show part of the list.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I edited my question to include the Generated Html code, while I look to see myself if I can get what I want with just Javascript, or if I need Zend to help with the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use jquery like this :

```
<script>
$("li>ul").addClass("'sub-menu'");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks again doydoy44, but I can't seem to get it working using that code. I looked around to try and find something similar but with no luck. It's a bit frustrating because all I need now is to add a class to that nested `<ul>` and I should be able to get it work..

Comment: Finally got it working with what you suggested! I just had to change it to this: 

`$("#layoutUl > li > ul").addClass('sub-menu');`

Comment: @Brendan: Thanks for the return. :) Happy for you and Good Luck. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, looking at the code, we can not add class to `ul` tags that are not on the 1st level.
So you can create your own view helper.
To do this:

1. Define the view helpers in `application.ini`.
   for example, with a 'My' library:

   ```
   resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper"
   ```
2. Add `My\View\Helper\Navigation.php` file

   ```
   <?php
   require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/Navigation.php';

   class My_View_Helper_Navigation
       extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation
   {
       const NS = 'My_View_Helper_Navigation';

       public function findHelper($proxy, $strict = true)
       {
           if (isset($this->_helpers[$proxy])) {
               return $this->_helpers[$proxy];
           }

           if (!$this->view->getPluginLoader('helper')->getPaths(self::NS)) {
               // Add navigation helper path at the beginning
               $paths = $this->view->getHelperPaths();
               $this->view->setHelperPath(null);

               $this->view->addHelperPath(
                       str_replace('_', '/', self::NS),
                       self::NS);

               foreach ($paths as $ns => $path) {
                   $this->view->addHelperPath($path, $ns);
               }
           }

           if ($strict) {
               $helper = $this->view->getHelper($proxy);
           } else {
               try {
                   $helper = $this->view->getHelper($proxy);
               } catch (Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception $e) {
                   return null;
               }
           }

           if (!$helper instanceof Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Helper) {
               if ($strict) {
                   require_once 'Zend/View/Exception.php';
                   $e = new Zend_View_Exception(sprintf(
                           'Proxy helper "%s" is not an instance of ' .
                           'Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Helper',
                           get_class($helper)));
                   $e->setView($this->view);
                   throw $e;
               }

               return null;
           }

           $this->_inject($helper);
           $this->_helpers[$proxy] = $helper;

           return $helper;
       }   
   }
   ```
3. Add `My\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu.php` file

   ```
   <?php
   require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/Menu.php';

   class My_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu
       extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu
   {
       protected $_ulClassDepth = '';

       protected function _renderMenu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container,
                                      $ulClass,
                                      $indent,
                                      $minDepth,
                                      $maxDepth,
                                      $onlyActive,
                                      $expandSibs,
                                      $ulId,
                                      $ulClassDepth)
       {
           $html = '';
           // find deepest active
           if ($found = $this->findActive($container, $minDepth, $maxDepth)) {
               $foundPage = $found['page'];
               $foundDepth = $found['depth'];
           } else {
               $foundPage = null;
           }

           // create iterator
           $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($container,
                               RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
           if (is_int($maxDepth)) {
               $iterator->setMaxDepth($maxDepth);
           }

           // iterate container
           $prevDepth = -1;
           foreach ($iterator as $page) {
               $depth = $iterator->getDepth();
               $isActive = $page->isActive(true);
               if ($depth < $minDepth || !$this->accept($page)) {
                   // page is below minDepth or not accepted by acl/visibilty
                   continue;
               } else if ($expandSibs && $depth > $minDepth) {
                   // page is not active itself, but might be in the active branch
                   $accept = false;
                   if ($foundPage) {
                       if ($foundPage->hasPage($page)) {
                           // accept if page is a direct child of the active page
                           $accept = true;
                       } else if ($page->getParent()->isActive(true)) {
                           // page is a sibling of the active branch...
                       $accept = true;
                   }
               }
               if (!$isActive && !$accept) {
                   continue;
               }
           } else if ($onlyActive && !$isActive) {
               // page is not active itself, but might be in the active branch
               $accept = false;
               if ($foundPage) {
                   if ($foundPage->hasPage($page)) {
                       // accept if page is a direct child of the active page
                       $accept = true;
                   } else if ($foundPage->getParent()->hasPage($page)) {
                       // page is a sibling of the active page...
                       if (!$foundPage->hasPages() ||
                           is_int($maxDepth) && $foundDepth + 1 > $maxDepth) {
                           // accept if active page has no children, or the
                           // children are too deep to be rendered
                           $accept = true;
                       }
                   }
               }

               if (!$accept) {
                   continue;
               }
           }

           // make sure indentation is correct
           $depth -= $minDepth;
           $myIndent = $indent . str_repeat('        ', $depth);

           if ($depth > $prevDepth) {
               $attribs = array();

               // start new ul tag
               if (0 == $depth) {
                   $attribs = array(
                       'class' => $ulClass,
                       'id'    => $ulId,
                   );
               }
               else{
                   $attribs = array(
                       'class' => $ulClassDepth,
                   );
               }


               // We don't need a prefix for the menu ID (backup)
               $skipValue = $this->_skipPrefixForId;
               $this->skipPrefixForId();

               $html .= $myIndent . '<ul'
                                  . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
                                  . '>'
                                  . self::EOL;

               // Reset prefix for IDs
               $this->_skipPrefixForId = $skipValue;
           } else if ($prevDepth > $depth) {
               // close li/ul tags until we're at current depth
               for ($i = $prevDepth; $i > $depth; $i--) {
                   $ind = $indent . str_repeat('        ', $i);
                   $html .= $ind . '    </li>' . self::EOL;
                   $html .= $ind . '</ul>' . self::EOL;
               }
               // close previous li tag
               $html .= $myIndent . '    </li>' . self::EOL;
           } else {
               // close previous li tag
               $html .= $myIndent . '    </li>' . self::EOL;
           }

           // render li tag and page
           $liClass = $isActive ? ' class="active"' : '';
           $html .= $myIndent . '    <li' . $liClass . '>' . self::EOL
                  . $myIndent . '        ' . $this->htmlify($page) . self::EOL;

           // store as previous depth for next iteration
           $prevDepth = $depth;
       }

       if ($html) {
           // done iterating container; close open ul/li tags
           for ($i = $prevDepth+1; $i > 0; $i--) {
               $myIndent = $indent . str_repeat('        ', $i-1);
               $html .= $myIndent . '    </li>' . self::EOL
                      . $myIndent . '</ul>' . self::EOL;
           }
           $html = rtrim($html, self::EOL);
       }

       return $html;
   }

   public function renderMenu(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null,
                              array $options = array())
   {
       if (null === $container) {
           $container = $this->getContainer();
       }

       $options = $this->_normalizeOptions($options);

       if ($options['onlyActiveBranch'] && !$options['renderParents']) {
           $html = $this->_renderDeepestMenu($container,
                                             $options['ulClass'],
                                             $options['indent'],
                                             $options['minDepth'],
                                             $options['maxDepth'],
                                             $options['ulId']);
       } else {
           $html = $this->_renderMenu($container,
                                      $options['ulClass'],
                                      $options['indent'],
                                      $options['minDepth'],
                                      $options['maxDepth'],
                                      $options['onlyActiveBranch'],
                                      $options['expandSiblingNodesOfActiveBranch'],
                                      $options['ulId'],
                                      $options['ulClassDepth']);
       }

       return $html;
   }

   protected function _normalizeOptions(array $options = array())
   {
       $options = parent::_normalizeOptions($options);
       if (!isset($options['ulClassDepth'])) {
           $options['ulClassDepth'] = $this->getUlClassDepth();
       }

       return $options;
   }

   public function setUlClassDepth($ulClassDepth)
   {
       if (is_string($ulClassDepth)) {
           $this->_ulClassDepth = $ulClassDepth;
       }

       return $this;
   }

   public function getUlClassDepth()
   {
       return $this->_ulClassDepth;
   }
   ```

   }
4. Call your menu with the new class `ulClassDepth` for 2nd level

   ```
   echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(Zend_Registry::get('user'),
                                                array('ulClassDepth' => 'sub-menu')
   );
   ```

Comment: Thanks doydoy44, It doesn't seem to be adding the 'sub-menu' tag at all. I'm still fiddling with it, and trying to find a way to get it work but no luck yet! Let me know if you think of anything else. :)

Comment: I update my answer in case things change something. :)

Comment: Hmm.. I tried all that, and it makes my whole menu disappear! I tried commenting out certain lines to see the different results, but I couldn't get the ulClass to appear. I'm re-reading the Zend Navigation Docs to see if I can spot anything I missed. Thanks again though doydoy44!

Comment: @Brendan: Promised, if I have another idea, I would post it. :)

Comment: I change my answer :)